# Flex, how to obtain peer ID from remote user connected to my stream?

Tags: apache-flex, video, stream, chat, p2p

I'm creating a p2p Cirrus video chat. **My current problem is how to automatically connected to subscriber, which connected to my stream.** After some googling I found that I can do it using next construction:

```
var clientObject:Object = new Object();
                    clientObject.onPeerConnect = function(callerns:NetStream):Boolean{              

                        return true;
                    }
```

My streams:

Send stream:

```
private function initSendNetStream():void{
                trace("initSendStream");

                sendStream = new NetStream(nc,NetStream.DIRECT_CONNECTIONS);
                sendStream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusEvent);
                var clientObject:Object = new Object();
                clientObject.onPeerConnect = function(callerns:NetStream):Boolean{              

                    return true;
                }

                sendStream.client = clientObject;
                sendStream.attachCamera(cam);
                sendStream.attachAudio(mic);
                sendStream.publish('video');
                log('Net Stream publish start');
            }
```

and Receive stream:

```
private function addContact(peerID:String):void {


            var nc2:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
            nc2.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, function (event:NetStatusEvent):void {
                trace('NetConnection status event (2): ' + event.info.code);
                var receiveNS:NetStream = new NetStream(nc2, /*ContactPeerID.text*/ peerID);
                receiveNS.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusEvent);
                receiveNS.play('video');

                var video:Video = new Video();
                video.attachNetStream(receiveNS);

                var uic:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
                uic.width = 320;
                uic.height = 240;
                uic.addChild(video);
                uic.toolTip = txtData.selectedItem.name;
                VideoStack.addChild(uic);

                //Clean ContactPeerID form
                ContactPeerID.text = '';
            });
            nc2.connect(SERVER_ADDRESS+DEVELOPER_KEY);              
        }
```

My idea is just put add contact function inside this construction:

```
 var clientObject:Object = new Object();
                        clientObject.onPeerConnect = function(callerns:NetStream):Boolean{              

                            return true;
                        }
```

However, for doing this I should detect and receive ID of subscriber to put it in a function. **My second problem- how to do that?** I'm trying to do it with remote Shared Object, but I don't know exactly how this structure should look in my case.

Hope someone help my with this questions. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what p2p connection architecture you're going to implement.
But just to find out the ID of the connected peer, you may try this:

```
callerns.farID
```

inside the onPeerConnect function.